# CPU tester with similar methodology as memtest86+

Tags: software-testing, hardware

I am looking for a CPU testing software. So, which would test every possible function of the CPU, many times and in many configurations, and displays its results.

In ideal case, it would be similar in its inner workings to [memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org/#screen), which does with RAM what I am seeking for CPU:

- minimalistic GUI
- boot-time functionality for ***OS-less hw control*** (i.e. it's independent from whatever OS is installed on the computer, as it includes its own minimalist OS)
- low-level asm or near-asm implementation

But note, these items are only advantages and not strict requirements.

Comment: Ok. I think "every possible function" is quite much if you consider how many different opcodes are there for Intel and Amd. Do you need a burn-in test or are you searching for microcode problems?

Comment: @Marged Yes that is true, especially for undocumented functions. Of course it is impossible to find every possible error in a cpu, but it is enough if an error would be found with a good chance. (Just as in the case of the RAM).

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: @peterh looked a bit confusing I guess. Hope my edit made it a bit clearer (please check it I got your idea right ;)

Comment: Good question and good edits.  Got my upvote.